# Best Practice for Jackson collection deserialisation

Tags: java, json, jackson, mutators

Let's say I have a simple class Person

```
public class Person{
  final List<String> names= Lists.newArrayList();

  public List<String> getNames(){
    return names;
  }
}
```

If I try to deserialise that with Jackson (2.2)

```
Person l = mapper.readValue(js,Person.class);
```

I get `Disabling Afterburner deserialization ....due to access error (type java.lang.IllegalAccessError ....`

This is because of **final** *names* list. To solve this I set `MapperFeature.ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS`  to `false`.

Is this the right solution or better just to make the list non-final?

Is there a Jackson method to use collection.add methods for initialising collections?

Or maybe there is a better way. What can be suggested here?

EDIT: I now found this setting:

> USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS (default: true) Controls whether "getters" that
>   return Collection or Map types can be used for "setting" values (same
>   as how JAXB API works with XML), so that separate "setter" method is
>   not needed. Even if enabled, explicit "setter" method will have
>   precedence over implicit getter-as-setter, if one exists.

Seems like exactly what I was looking and it is on by default. So why was it ignored then?

Answer (score 2):

Working with immutable Objects in your application is a best practice, but on the boundaries to the (non-Java) outside world, you usually have to refrain from using them.

In most Serialization technologies, everything works fine when your Objects are "well-behaved" (mutable, with getters and setters according to the JavaBeans-standard). There's usually some way around that but in my experience it's easiest to just make the damn thing mutable, as long as you're not going to reference it from other Java Code. (if worst comes to worst, create a dedicated serialization DTO)

Comment: Yes, I agree in general. But this is specifically about collection fields and Jackson. To eliminate any chance of empty collection fields I just create them in initialiser and set them final. One can always add elements to it through collection's add methods. So state of collection is mutable, but not itself. What I was looking if there is a way to make Jackson use these add methods to initialise collections.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is due to a problem with combination of things. Specifically, can you try your approach without enabling Afterburner first? If this works, then this is an issue with Afterburner module's handling of processing -- it is possible since code path involved here differs from default one.
Make sure to use latest version; 2.3.0 was just released.

Comment: Yes, it works without afterburner. But with afterburner I get IllegalAccessError and with latest version as well. Then I have to enable ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS for it to work with Afterburner, which is freaky, as I don't know the implications. This seems like a bug in afterburner. According to documentation it is supposed to add elements to collection rather than changing it.

Comment: I would file a bug for Afterburner; it is quite possible this would be easy to fix.

Comment: Thanks, @Staxman, already reported a bug. I just wasn't sure if it was an expected behaviour or not.